# Why does my update statement update every row?

Tags: sql-server, update

### **Problem:**

My final update statement should error out due to syntax and rollback the transaction, the expected error should be similar to:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 45 Invalid column name 'FakeTest1'

I'm curious as to why SQL Server updates every row in the column when the subquery referencing a non-existent column is allowed to execute.

### **Background**

I am creating a Temp table with two columns, `FakeID` and `FakeVarchar`.

```
 SELECT  [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
 INTO [#T]
 FROM [CTE];
```

When my `UPDATE` statement uses this `WHERE` clause specifying the column [ID] in the `SELECT SUBQUERY`, it updates the entire table instead of erroring on parsing the command.

```
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT [ID]
    FROM [#T]
);
```

The column that should be in the subquery for it to run correctly would be `FakeID`. This statement obviously works and it updates as expected.

```
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT [FakeID]
    FROM [#T]
);
```

When I replace FakeID / ID with any other column name, it fails as expected.

```
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT [NotActuallyAColumnInThisTableEither]
    FROM [#T]
);
```

### **Full SQL code that updates the entire table when it should error out instead**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableSource', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource]
( 
             [FakeID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [#T];
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableDestination', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
( 
             [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableSource]( [FakeID], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Three' ), ( 4, 'Four' );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]( [ID], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Five' ), ( 5, 'Four' );

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
         FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource])
     SELECT  [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
     INTO [#T]
     FROM [CTE];

UPDATE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
  SET [FakeVarchar] = [src].[FakeVarchar]
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource] AS [SRC]
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT [ID]
    FROM [#T]
);

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource];

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];

SELECT *
FROM [#t];
```

### **Full SQL Code that is syntactically correct and updates the values as expected**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableSource', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource]
( 
             [FakeID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [#T];
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableDestination', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
( 
             [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableSource]( [FakeID], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Three' ), ( 4, 'Four' );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]( [ID], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Five' ), ( 5, 'Four' );

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
         FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource])
     SELECT  [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
     INTO [#T]
     FROM [CTE];

UPDATE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
  SET [FakeVarchar] = [src].[FakeVarchar]
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource] AS [SRC]
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT [FakeID]
    FROM [#T]
);

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource];

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];

SELECT *
FROM [#t];
```

### **What I discovered**

The `WHERE` clause seems to be what allows this `UPDATE` to happen. For example, I'll change the column name in `FakeTableDestination` from `FakeID` to `Test`. I can then reference the `Test` column from `#T`even though the column is still aliased as `FakeID`. This causes the entire column to update during the update statement.

**SQL Code Illustrating That Behavior**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableSource', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource]
( 
             [FakeID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [#T];
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableDestination', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
( 
             [Test] INT PRIMARY KEY, [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableSource]( [FakeID], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Three' ), ( 4, 'Four' );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]( [Test], [FakeVarchar] )
VALUES( 1, 'One' ), ( 2, 'Two' ), ( 3, 'Five' ), ( 5, 'Four' );

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
         FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource])
     SELECT  [FakeID], [FakeVarchar]
     INTO [#T]
     FROM [CTE];


UPDATE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
  SET [FakeVarchar] = [src].[FakeVarchar]
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource] AS [SRC]
WHERE [FakeTableDestination].[Test] IN
(
    SELECT [Test]
    FROM [#T]
);

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource];

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];

SELECT *
FROM [#t];
```

### **Things I tried/thought about**

> What if ID is a name of a column in the temp table and it's hidden?

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM [tempdb].[sys].[syscolumns]
WHERE [name] = 'FakeID';
```

Ok, I see ID listed here and I see other columns, like xtype, typestat, etc. So what if I try one of those other columns instead? I tried substituting xtype / typestat and they failed on syntax too.

> Maybe it's because you're using a temp table?

I get this same behavior with table variables and physical tables.

**Table Variable Code**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableSource', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableSource]
([FakeID]      INT
 PRIMARY KEY, 
 [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FakeTableDestination', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
([ID]          INT
 PRIMARY KEY, 
 [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

GO

DECLARE @T TABLE
([FakeID]      INT
 PRIMARY KEY, 
 [FakeVarchar] VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableSource]
(
       [FakeID], 
       [FakeVarchar]
)
VALUES
       (1, 
        'One'),
       (2, 
        'Two'),
       (3, 
        'Three'),
       (4, 
        'Four');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
(
       [ID], 
       [FakeVarchar]
)
VALUES
       (1, 
        'One'),
       (2, 
        'Two'),
       (3, 
        'Five'),
       (5, 
        'Four');

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT 
                [FakeID], 
                [FakeVarchar]
         FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource])

     INSERT INTO @T
     (
            [FakeID], 
            [FakeVarchar]
     )
     SELECT 
            [FakeID], 
            [FakeVarchar]
     FROM [CTE];

UPDATE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
  SET 
      [FakeVarchar] = [src].[FakeVarchar]
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource] AS [SRC]
WHERE 
      [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT 
           [ID]
    FROM @T
);
```

**Physical Table Code Snippet**

```
SELECT 
     [FakeID], 
     [FakeVarchar]
INTO dbo.T
FROM [CTE];

UPDATE [dbo].[FakeTableDestination]
  SET 
      [FakeVarchar] = [src].[FakeVarchar]
FROM [dbo].[FakeTableSource] AS [SRC]
WHERE 
      [FakeTableDestination].[ID] IN
(
    SELECT 
           [ID]
    FROM T
);
```

> What if you change the `UPDATE` to `NOT IN`?

It does not update any of the rows in that column.

> What versions of SQL Server did you try this on?
>   SQL Server 2012 SP1, SP2, 2016 SP 2.
>
> What did the query plans look like?

[Query I believe should error on syntax](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By_b3GqXV)

[Query that updates correctly](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1iV2fqQE)